# Android: app incompatible with Huawei?

Tags: android

I have two apps listed on the marketplace.  One of them is a free demo application, and the second is a second key application that unlocks the full version of the first application.  I received a report from a user that the demo installs on their Huawei, but the market lists they application as "incompatible".  I haven't received any other reports of this, and can't find anything useful on Google.  The two manifest xmls are below, the demo app first and the key app second.  Could this be caused by the check license permission?  In android market developer console, the "supported devices" section is the exact same for both apps:

> Supported Devices [Learn More] This
>   application is only available to
>   devices with these features, as
>   defined in your application manifest.
>
> Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE
>   XLARGE
>
> Required device features
>   android.hardware.touchscreen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.1">
    <application ...>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package=...
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <application ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Assuming they have the Android Market application on their device, they should not have a problem with the CHECK_LICENSE permission. My only guess is that the user is not located in a country you've made the app available for sale in.

Comment: All countries are checked in my developer console.  Also, the user says that the "purchase" button display in their marketplace, but he gets message saying that it is incompatible when he tries to purchase it.

Comment: His device is listed when I view "supported devices" and the user is in Costa Rica.  In my market developer console, I have the "Rest of the world, except for:" checkbox selected, and none of the following exclusionary checkboxes selected.  Meaning, it should be available for purchase in Costa Rica?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to do is download both apps from Market, pull them off the device (with "adb pull"), and then use "aapt dump badging " on each of them.  This prints out the "badging" information for the app; it is the same thing that Market uses to determine filtering and other things about the app.  If there is nothing different between these, then the problem is not in how you have built your apps.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The user eventually reported back that the problem was related to purchasing paid apps in Costa Rica.